# Strategies to implementing a conditional Navbar if a user is logged in or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

**Background**: I am creating a very basic application with 4 different capabilities: Signup, Login, Searching, and Creating content. As of right now, I can log in to users and prevent unauthorized users from going to protected routes. This is shown below in my `Protected.js` component. However, I am struggling to figure out a way to also **conditionally display a login/logout button in my navigation bar located in my `App.js`**.

**Followup Questions**: Should I move the authentication logic out of my `Login.js` route and into my main `App.js` component and pass the state down? Wouldn't that be very inefficient, because every time I am rendering a new view, the `App.js` is performing another fetch with my backend API to verify if the user has a non-expired session? This might appear trivial to some, but I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around how to conditionally show a login/logout button efficiently.  I have looked into Context API, so I would be open to some advice down that route if you feel necessary, but I am not familiar with Redux(*I just began to React a week ago*). I am looking for well-thought-out strategies, so I would greatly appreciate it if you could do your best to provide complete and coherent responses. I really appreciate it.

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
                        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">My Application</Navbar.Brand>
                        <Nav className="mr-auto">
                            <Link to="/signup" className="nav-link">Signup</Link>
                            <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">Login</Link>
                            <Link to="/feed" className="nav-link">Search</Link>
                            <Link to="/create-post" className="nav-link">Create</Link>
                        </Nav>
                        <Form inline>
                            <Button variant="outline-primary">Logout</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </Navbar>
                </div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path = '/signup' component = {Signup} />
                    <Route path = '/login' component = {Login} />
                    <Route path = '/feed' component = {Feed} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path = '/create-post' component = {CreatePost} />
                </Switch>

            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

**Login.js**

```
 class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            username: "",
            password: ""
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmitForm = this.handleSubmitForm.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        //console.log(event.target.name)
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    }

    handleSubmitForm() {
        const user = {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        const url = 'http://localhost:9000/api/login'

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            if (data.status === 1) {
                this.props.history.push('/feed')
            }
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error', error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <Card className="card-login" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>Login</Card.Title>
                    <Form>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Control placeholder ="Username"
                                          name = "username"
                                          value = {this.state.username}
                                          onChange = {this.handleChange}/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Control type ="password"
                                          placeholder="Password"
                                          name = "password"
                                          value = {this.state.password}
                                          onChange = {this.handleChange} />
                        </Form.Group>                   
                    <Button variant ="primary"
                            value="Submit"
                            onClick={this.handleSubmitForm}>Submit
                    </Button>
                    </Form>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>         
        </div>)
    }
}
```

**Protectedroute.js**

```
class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            isLoading: true
        }
        this.isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.isAuthenticated()
    }

    isAuthenticated() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:9000/api/auth'
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((data) => {
            if (data === 'true') {
                this.setState({
                    isAuthenticated: true,
                    isLoading: false
                })
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    isAuthenticated: false,
                    isLoading: false
                })
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error', err)
        })
    }
    render() {
        const Component = this.props.component
        if (this.state.isLoading === true) {
            return (<div>Loading</div>)
        }
        return(
            <Route render={(props) => this.state.isAuthenticated && !this.state.isLoading ? (<Component {...this.props}/>) : (<Redirect to ='/login' />)} />
        )
            
    }
}
```

**api.js (Express Backend)**

```
router.post('/login', function(req,res,next) {
    const query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = TRIM(?) AND pass = TRIM(?)"
    database.query(query1, [req.body.username, req.body.password])
    .then((result) => {
        if (result.length) {
            if (req.session.username) {
                res.json({'message': 'You are already logged in', 'status': 0})
            } else {
                req.session.username = req.body.username
                res.json({'message': 'You have successfully logged in', 'status': 1})
            }
        } else {
            if (req.session.username) {
                res.json({'message': 'You are already logged in', 'status': 0})
            } else {
                res.json({'message': 'Incorrect Credentials', 'status': 0})
            }
        }
    }).catch((err) => res.send(err))
})



router.get('/auth', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.username) {
        res.send(true)
    } else {
        res.send(false)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is clear need for the global state and you can use React Context, Redux or even set auth state in `App` component, pass methods, which change state ie. `setAuth`, as props to `Login` component.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setAuth = this.setAuth.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false
    };
  }

  setAuth(value) {
    this.setState({
      isAuthenticated: value
    });
  }
```

```html
<Route path='/login' component={() => <Login setAuth={this.setAuth} />} />
```

> Should I move the authentication logic out of my Login.js route and
>   into my main App.js component and pass the state down? Wouldn't that
>   be very inefficient, because every time I am rendering a new view, the
>   App.js is performing another fetch with my backend api to verify if
>   the user has a non-expired session?

Did you mean the logic which happens in `Protectedroute` component? I would extract that to `App` component as you said because in a scenario

```html
<ProtectedRoute path = '/create-post' component = {CreatePost} />
<ProtectedRoute path = '/post-list' component = {PostList} />
<ProtectedRoute path = '/update-post' component = {UpdatePost} />
```

It would check if user is authenticated multiple times when you want to get to `'/update-post'` section.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. The first response you gave is a great example to modify App state inside a child component. However, regarding your second response, I want to make sure that I understand you correctly: Do you recommend I get rid of `ProtectedRoute` and move all of my fetching authentication logic from `ProtectedRoute`  and into `App` ? If that is the case, wouldn't my `App` component perform a fetch every time a new component mounts? @Józef Podlecki

Comment: If you place request in `componentDidMount`  and then change state then yes it would still perform fetch again. But `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps)` comes to the rescue and there you can make a very simple predicate which ignores `isAuthenticated` prop change or just returns `false` all the time

Comment: Very well.This is the accepted answer. Thank you for providing feedback. @ Józef Podlecki